# How to 'pass on' a return value?

Tags: python, function, return

I have class with several functions that compute some quantities. A global Boolean controls if the functions should either return the value or store it as an attribute. I want to have a  single `_return_value()` function that accomplishes this, rather than writing `if store_value … else return …` in each of the class functions. A simple `_return_value = return` gives a syntax error. Here is a minimal (not) working example:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, store_value=False):

        if store_value:
            self._return_function = self._store_value
        else:
            self._return_function = self._return_value

    def _return_value(self, value):
        return value

    def _store_value(self, value):
        setattr(self, 'stored_value', value)

    def add_one(self, value):
        self._return_function(value+1)
```

It works perfectly for storing the value as a class attribute, i.e.

```
objFoo = foo(store_value=True)
objFoo.add_one(41)
print(objFoo.stored_value)  # prints '42'
```

But the `add_one()` function returns `None` when I use

```
objFoo2 = foo(store_value=False)
print(objFoo2.add_one(41))  # expect to return '42', but returns 'None'
```

How do I manage that `_return_value()` returns the value 'all the way' so that `add_one()` returns 42 in this case?

Comment: Huh, `setattr(self, 'stored_value', value)` sure is a weird way of writing `self.stored_value = value`.

Comment: you really don't want to do this.

Comment: Just remember, keep it simple. The more complex you make it means the harder it is to figure out what is broken later

Comment: What's the reason for switching between the two modes? Could you just do both all the time: store the value and return it?

Comment: "A global Boolean" <- This immediately indicates that you should probably reconsider what you're doing. @JohnKugelman makes a good point. You can have the method _always_ return the value, but just not do anything with it (meaning don't assign the value, just call the method) when you don't want it to "return". All methods will always return _at least_ `None`, unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `add_one` forward `_return_function`'s return value.

```
def add_one(self, value):
    return self._return_function(value+1)
```

- If `_return_function` is set to `_store_value` then `add_one` will return `None`.
- If `_return_function` is set to `_return_value` then `add_one` will forward the returned value.

Answer (score -1):

Your add_one method returns None because it's missing a return statement. When a python function doesn't contain a return statement, it's default return value is None:

```
def add_one(self, value):
    self._return_function(value+1)
```

This should be:

```
def add_one(self, value):
    return self._return_function(value+1)
```

To be honest, though, I have no clue what problem your class is trying to solve. Maybe explaining a bit about the purpose would lead to answers that suggest better ways to achieve it.

---

(Edit: I'll assume the downvote is for the above paragraph, so l'll expand on it a bit)

It seems like your class could be just as easily written in other ways which are arguably cleaner. I especially don't think that it's a good idea to have `add_one` perform two different functions depending on a flag you pass at object creation time. That's bound to get you in a situation with a hard-to-debug bug.

Consider:

```
>>> foobar = foo()
>>> barfoo = foo(True)    
>>> x = foobar.add_one(5)
>>> y = barfoo.add_one(5)
>>> x
6
>>> y   # y is None!
>>>
```

From just looking at the two identical-looking calls to `add_one`, it's impossible to decide which one will return an integer value and which one will return None. That makes it hard to reason about your program.

The same goes for the `stored_value` attribute for objects of class `foo` - you can't know when you write your class methods whether that attribute will even exist because it depends on a flag you pass in at runtime, so you'll have to clutter your method's code with tests to make sure you're not raising an `AttributeError`.